# If $f\in\mathcal{L}^{1}(\mathbb{R})$, with $f_t(x) = f(x-t)$, show $\lim_{t\rightarrow0}|| f - f_t ||_{1}=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f\in\mathcal{L}^{1}(\mathbb{R})$. For each $t\in\mathbb{R}$, define $f_t:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $f_t(x) = f(x-t)$. Prove that $$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}||f-f_t||_1 = 0,$$ i.e. show that $$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\int_{R}|f-f_t|d\lambda =0$$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Hi, I'm working on this problem and honestly am just a bit confused by all the moving pieces to consider. I saw the [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2888174/let-f-in-lp-r-for-1-leq-p-infty-and-let-f-tx-fx-t) post here, but the answer provided was a bit above my head.

To start, I know that every $f_t\in\mathcal{L}^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ since $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_t|d\lambda = \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f|d\lambda$ by the invariance property of the meausre. But I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Any advice on how to advance is appreciated =)

Comment: The idea here is that you want $f(x)$ and $f(x - t)$ to be similar in value when $t$ is small so that their difference is small. However this is by no means guaranteed for a general function in $\mathcal L_1$. Hence we approximate it by a continuous function to make the proof work. What parts of the proof you linked do you not understand?

Comment: @bitesizebo I understand now that the $\phi$ they used is an approximation by an continuous function for $f$, but I don't understand why we then have someth $\phi_t$ that is within $\varepsilon/3$ that is also that close to $f_t$. Using that idea, I figured that $\phi_t$ is the was the continuous approximation for $f_t$, but even then I don't see how to show that $phi_t $ is close to $\phi$.

Comment: @bitesizebo Really I guess where I got stuck was showing that $\phi_t\rightarrow\phi$ as $t\rightarrow0$ in $\mathcal{L}^{1}(R)$ where $\phi$ and $\phi_t$ are the continuous approximations of $f$ and $f_t$ respectively

Comment: As mentioned in the question the more general concept being used is uniform continuity, but since they assume that $\phi$ is smooth we can take a shortcut. Try using the mean value theorem to bound $\lvert \phi_t(x) - \phi(x) \rvert$. This gives a bound on $\lVert \phi_t - \phi \rVert_{\infty}$ which then gives a bound on $\lVert \phi_t - \phi \rVert_1$ since the $\phi$ are compactly supported.

Comment: @bitesizebo but then why does this also provide a bound on $||\phi_t - f_t||_1$? If we are getting the $\phi_t$ from $\phi$ somehow, then what gives it the relation to $f_t$.

Comment: Do you see why $\lVert \phi_t - f_t \rVert_1 = \lVert \phi - f \rVert_1$?